# AngularJS 1.4.x - Run Node script from angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I've a node script to read meta-tags of mp3 files.

**Node**

```
var jsmediatags = require("jsmediatags");

module.exports = function readMeta(file) {
  jsmediatags.read(file , {
    onSuccess: function(tag) {
      return tag;
    },
    onError: function(error) {
      return (':(', error.type, error.info);
    }
  })
}
```

I want to use this script in angular app.

**Angular**

```
$scope.$watch('currentPlaying', function() {
      if(!angular.isUndefined($scope.currentPlaying)){
        let url = $scope.currentPlaying.url; //file path
        readMeta(url)
      }
```

Comment: Yeah, no. That's absolutely not how it works. Node runs on a server, and Angular in the browser. The function is defined on another _machine_ and in a different environment than where Angular runs. There is absolutely no way you can invoke it like this. You have to contact Node on the server somehow and ask it to execute the function. Currently, it's like you have a pen, you write on a sheet of paper, and you expect the text to appear on another sheet of paper in a different building. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: maybe you can try to upload the file to the server